# How to resfresh SWT Table after deleting a row

Tags: java, swt

I have a SWT Table and a couple of buttons to add and remove rows in the table, the add button works fine, after clicking it the new row is immediately added at the end of the table but when I select a row and then click the delete button seems that nothing happens, but when I click on the table it is refreshed displaying the correct result, the question is, how can I refresh the table after deleting a row?

I tried calling this methods with no success:

```
table.redraw();
table.refresh();
```

This is how my table looks like:

```
Table table = new Table(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

And my Delete button:

```
Button btnRemove = new Button(container, SWT.NONE);
btnRemove.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        table.remove(table.getSelectionIndices()); 
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no need to refresh a Table after removing items. Just calling `Table#remove()` should do. Are you sure that `getSelectionIndices()` isn't empty and contains existing indices? Alternatively you can dispose of the selected items via `TableItem#dispose()`.

Comment: Found the problem, please see answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I have a Text component inside the rows, so If I delete the row seems that the Text field remains, so the solution is to dispose the Text before removing the row, like this:

```
textField.dispose();
table.remove(table.getSelectionIndex());
```

Comment: This didn't help for me. I got Table with row remove Button added to cell via TableEditor. I'm disposing TableEditor by editor.getEditor().dispose(); then calling 
            table.remove(indexToRemove);
            table.redraw();
the first time I do it, it works ok, the second row I try to remove with the buttons, it removes the row and the buttons, the below row moves up to fill empty space, but lower buttons stay at the same place. Only when I click on Table, it gets updated.